# I want to combine images of different sizes. (Image Magick)

Tags: append, imagemagick

I want to combine 1.png and 2.png

When I combine the two files, I want to change the height of 2.png to the height of 1.png

I used the append command, but I didn't get the result I wanted.

Below is the command I used.

```
convert +append 1.png 2.png result.png
```

Please teach me the way!! Thanks !

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omgcj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick 6, you would need to get the height of image 1 first in a separate command. For example on a Unix-based system:

```
ht=`convert image1.png -format "%h" info:`
convert image1.png \( image2.png -resize x${ht} \) +append result.png
```

In Imagemagick 7, you can do it all in one command line:

```
magick image1.png -set option:ht "%ht" \( image2.png -resize "x%[ht]" +append result.png
```

Example:

Input

[image]

[image]

```
ht=`convert monet2.jpg -format "%h" info:`
convert monet2.jpg \( zelda1.jpg -resize x${ht} \) +append result.png
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I can't use the code you answered because I'm using Windows 10, but thank you for your answer. 

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Windows. Syntax is slightly different with respect to the saving and using of variables for IM 6. On IM 7, just remove the \ from the parentheses and the command should work.

Answer (score 0):

convert -append img1.png img2.png result.png